# Hooks afterUpdate and afterDestroy not called

Tags: strongloop

My goal is to send some request after certain model was created, updated or deleted. So I implemented the following:

```
module.exports = function(TerminalUser) {

var http = require('http'); 

var tsReloadUser = function(id) {

    var options = {                     
        auth: 'user:pwd',
        host: 'host.domain.local',
        port: 8080,
        path: '/CmdUserCacheRefresh?userid=' + id,
        method: 'GET'
    };

    http.request(options, function(res) {

        console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
        console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
        }); 

    }).end();
}

TerminalUser.afterSave = function(next) {

    console.log('afterSave');

    tsReloadUser(this.id);

    next();
};

TerminalUser.afterUpdate = function(next) {

    console.log('afterUpdate');

    tsReloadUser(this.id);

    next();
}

TerminalUser.afterDestroy = function(next) {

    console.log('afterDestroy');

    tsReloadUser(this.id);

    next();
};
```

};

The hook afterSave is call when an entity was created and everything runs as expected. But for some strange reason neither afterUpdate/Destroy is called nor a error message is thrown when a user updates or delete an entity instance (the data is successfully stored in the database). Can anyone give me a hint whats going on?

Comment: I'm looking into it, will get back to you soon.

Comment: It seems related to [issue 159](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/issues/159) as it works with the given hack.

Comment: Looks like it. Will have to wait until someone on the team resolves it I guess.

Answer (score 0):

See an example in my new repo: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-faq-model-hooks

> There is an issue with `afterDestroy`, the issue is waiting to be resolved

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement your logic with `changed` and `deleted` [Model's Events](http://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#model)